# Splitting a string by a backslash with preg_split() throws an error

Tags: php, regex, string

Examplestring:

```
\Foo\Bar\Baz
```

(namespace: `\Foo\Bar` class: `Baz`)

I'm trying to get the namespace and class name into a variable, `$namespace` and `$className`.

The section before the last `\` is the namespace, and after is the class name.

I tried doing it with:

```
preg_split('/\\(?=[a-z]+$)/i', '\Foo\Bar\Baz')
```

of which the regex works fine [here](http://www.regexr.com/3au2i) but not in PHP:

> **Warning**: preg_split(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 11

To my understanding my regex says: "Match any backslash, but only if the characters after it until the end matches the characters within this positive lookahead.".

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Between single quotes you need three backslashes to obtain one literal backslash in a pattern. Note (four works too because one backslash is ignored)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) and [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to extract the namespace and the classname like this:

```
$str = "\Foo\Bar\Baz";
echo $namespace = dirname($str);
echo $classname = basename($str);
```

output:

```
\Foo\Bar
Baz
```

Answer (score 3):

For a literal backslash, you need four backslashes in a regex string:

```
preg_split('/\\\\(?=[a-z]+$)/i', '\Foo\Bar\Baz')
```

Otherwise, `\\(` will match a literal `(` character, and the closing `)` causes the "unmatched parenthesis" error.

Comment: I'm going to accept @Rizier123's answer since his answer is a better solution to the complete problem I'm trying to solve, but I gave yours an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a regex expert, so this is how I'd do it:

```
$pieces = explode('\', "\Foo\Bar\Baz");
$numPieces = count($pieces);
$className = $pieces[$numPieces - 1];
// assuming you need only the last-but-one piece as namespace
$namespace = $pieces[$numPieces - 2];

// but if you need the whole thing from the start till last backslash as namespace then:
array_pop($pieces);
$namespace = implode('\',$pieces);
```

I hope it's quite clear by the code itself and it's the thing that you wish to achieve.

Comment: I'd use `array_reverse` rather than a static value so you'll know `0` is always the last index.